# Not getting a fbclid from users clicking on my ads

Tags: facebook, url-parameters

I am trying to store the value of a fbclid to our internal systems for various reasons. I ave built something that works in that it stores the fbclid from a url parameter i.e. ?fbclid=abc123

The problem is that it only works when I physically add that parameter to the end of my url.

On the ads that we have running we don't seem to be receiving any fbclid on the url. I thought that all links from Facebook had one on?

I can't find any documentation or reason why these wouldn't be being added by Facebook. With Google Ads, the parameters are added every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we are facing some similar issue that sometimes in in-app browser we are not getting fbclid but as per document we can find it inside cookie so i've compiled this script and some information. hopefully this help.

just include this script in your code and it will copy fbclid from cookie to url if it does not exist in url

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb_cookie_clid_extractor

https://github.com/furqanfreed/facebook-cookie-clid-extractor